# Direction of Centripetal Force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, fluid-statics, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

Centripetal force is directed towards the center, then why does an object placed on a rotating disc move outwards?

On the other hand,  when a particle is placed in a cylindrical container containing water that rotates, the particle moves towards the center.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the force which throws a body on a rotating disk outwards centrifugal force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/425315/)

Comment: You are conflating _[centripetal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force)_ (a force that causes an object to follow a circular path in an inertial frame of reference), with _[centrifugal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrifugal_force)_ (a ["pseudo-force"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fictitious_force) that seems to cause things to move away from the center of rotation in a rotating frame of reference.)